# NoSuchElementException on opening BTC and adding indicator in tradingview using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, tradingview-api

At first I opened the link through `driver.get` and pressed on a button through `execute_script` but when I try to press using `execute_script` on another button on the new tab which the first button opened it gives that exception.

I want to open tradingview open btc and click on indicators.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\Chrome driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSDTPERP/ideas/?exchange=BINANCE")

advanced = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#anchor-page-1 > div > div.tv-category-header__buttons.tv-category-header__buttons--adaptive.tv-category-header__buttons--hide-if_bigger-than_phone > div > a.btn-Phr0VjiT.btnDesktop-Phr0VjiT.button-OvB35Th_.size-large-OvB35Th_.color-brand-OvB35Th_.variant-secondary-OvB35Th_.with-start-icon-OvB35Th_.with-end-icon-OvB35Th_")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",advanced)

time.sleep(20)
chart = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#header-toolbar-chart-styles > div")
driver.execute_script("argument[0].click()",chart)
```

I tried to press button after the first button opened a new tab called indicators but gives that exception I am trying to open tradingview and open btc after that click on indicators.

Answer (score 0):

When a new tab is opened and you want to do something with selenium, first you have to switch to that tab:

```
driver.switch_to.window( driver.window_handles[-1] )
```

The `[-1]` means that you are switching to the last opened tab.

So put this command right after `time.sleep(20)`